# jQuery populate array merging parent and child XML tags

Tags: jquery, xml, arrays, tags, parent

I'm building up a function in jQuery that populate an array from an XML.
The XML comes out of another application, so I cannot change it.

The function is meant to preload image after the array is created.
Everything works well except that I am not able to distinguish child tags with same name under different parent tags.

Well, here is the jQuery code:

```
 (function() {
{
setTimeout(function(){

var splashArray = new Array();
// Load the Splash XML file and assign each image within to an array
$.get('images.xml', function(xml) {
```

The problem is here:

```
 $('album', xml).each(function (i) {
        var path = $(this).attr("lgpath");
        $('img', xml).each(function (i) {
         splashArray.push("/fotografie-matrimonio/" + path + $(this).attr("src"));
```

see below for the problem!

```
    });
    });
    work_with_splash();
});
function work_with_splash () {
    Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
      }
     return size;
    };
    // Get the size of an object
    var size = Object.size(splashArray);
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) new Image().src = splashArray[i];
                /*alert(result[X]);*/   
} //closes the spalsh Call

}, 1000);
};
```

and here the XML structure:

```
<album id="1" lgpath="thePath 1/" ...>
    <img src="name of photo 1" ....></img>
    <img src="name of photo 2"....></img>
    <img src="name of photo 3"....></img>
</album>
<album id="2" lgpath="thePath 2/" ...>
    <img src="name of photo 1" ....></img>
    <img src="name of photo 2"....></img>
    <img src="name of photo 3"....></img>
</album>
```

The script works, but what it does is the it load for each album path all the img src (also the ones of the others album path.

What I want to do is: to process the img tags in groups by the parent tags.
I don't know if I am clear!

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved!

Easy...

just change the code from:

```
 $('album', xml).each(function (i) {
    var path = $(this).attr("lgpath");
    $('img', xml).each(function (i) {
     splashArray.push("/fotografie-matrimonio/" + path + $(this).attr("src"));
```

to:

```
 $('img', xml).each(function (i) {
        var path = $(this).parent().attr("lgpath");
        splashArray.push("/fotografie-matrimonio/" + path + $(this).attr("src"));
    });
```

using the .parent() method.

Hope it will help somebody!

Cheers :)

Comment: what I need now is to set a after page is loaded, because page will wait to cache all the images like that, which is definitely not good! Any suggestion?

Comment: For the after page is loaded we can use the $(window).load(function()). At the bottom of the page is better! Just before the close of body tag. Hope wil help somebody!!